# Logging in FlutterActivity not appearing in VS Code

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I'm developing a Flutter app, using VS Code. I've added some logging to my `FlutterActivity`, as follows:

```
package com.example.package

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    val TAG = this.javaClass.name

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Log.d(TAG, "Hello World!")
    }

//...
```

When I run my app, I expect to see "Hello World!" displayed in the VS Code `Debug Console`, along with all of the other Android logging. However, I'm not seeing anything. What am I doing wrong?

Updates:

1. In Android Studio, the logging appears correctly in the Logcat tab.
2. With VS Code, if I start debugging my app with the tablet locked, and then unlock it, the logging *does* appear.
3. If I use `adb logcat`, the logging does/does not appear depending on which `--regex` filter I use, even though the regex matches the logs I'm expecting.